# How to escape single quotes in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am converting Template Toolkit files, e.g. `Pieces` becomes `[% l('Pieces') %]`.

I encountered one problem. What is the proper conversion of `'Title'`? This is not correct: `[% l(''Title'') %]`

In short, how to escape `'`?

Comment: "tool template"? "template tool"? Do you mean "Template Toolkit"? http://template-toolkit.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can just use alternate quotes. TT approximates regular perl quoting so you can use double or single–

```
[% l("'Title'") %]
```